# Nginx, assigning appropriate values for: worker_processes, worker_connections, and worker_rlimit_nofile

Tags: nginx, worker-processes

There are many resources adopt some facts (e.g., worker_processes: setting it to the number of available CPU cores), and then they change the values without any rule; by continued monitoring.

I prefer to have some values to start with as a good start, and then I need to know how we should increase/decrease that values accordingly.